# Xubuntu Startup With No Keyboard

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard, surface

I have a Surface Pro and first I tried to dual boot ubuntu and Windows 8. Ubuntu would freeze after about a minute after boot but the keyboard worked fine. So I took ubuntu off and hours later finally removed grub. Anyways turns out the Surface just can't handle ubuntu. I decided to try xubuntu on the system. I now have the Surface pro dual booting xubuntu and windows 10. On windows 10 the keyboard works but on xubuntu the surface keyboard does not work. I have seen many articles saying "Oh, type this to use your keyboard!" But, I cant, because the keyboard doesnt work...

Answer (score 0):

I found out the fix for this. You only have to do it once. Since you cannot log in to your username, use log in as a guest, open terminal and type random stuff. The keyboard does work! Log out of guest, choose your username. Done. I dont know if this is a real solution, but that is what I did and it worked :)